# Element exists at List that have same name

Tags: java, collections, contains

I have a List at java. My class has fields and one of them is: `name`. Lets assume that:

```
List<MyClass> mylist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
MyClass myElement = new MyClass();
myElement.setName("xxx");
```

So how can I check is there any element at List which contains same name with `myElement` variable and retrieve that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `MyClass` implements `equals()` in a way that makes two `MyClass` instances equal if they have the same name, then you can simply do:

```
int index = mylist.indexOf(myElement);
MyClass myListElement = mylist.get(index);
```

Unfortunately there is no "get the element that is `equal()` to this" method in the `Collection`/`List` API, which *could* be implemented in a more efficient manner.

If you *don't* have such a `equals()` implementation (or don't *want* it for some reason), then you'll have to do it the boring, old-fashioned way:

```
MyClass listElement = null;
for (MyClass mc : mylist) {
  if (myElement.getName().equals(mc.getName()) {
    listElement = mc;
    break;
  }
}
// if listElement is non-null here, then we found it
```

Comment: Just I am wondering that. Is it better not to use break inside a for loop and using while loop?

Comment: @kamaci: better by what metric? I don't believe in the "`break` and `continue` are always evil" mantra and in that case I think it's pretty readable, so I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If using [Apache CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#find%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) is an option, the `find` method does exactly that :

```
CollectionUtils.find(myList, new Predicate(){
  public boolean evaluate(Object o){
    return name.equals(((MyClass) o).getName());
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `equals()` method for `MyClass` to return `true` if the `name` fields are equal (String's `equal()`).

Comment: While that would solve the problem, it would open a can of worms if `MyClass` needed to define equality on other/more properties than `name`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in, you have to do this manually:

```
MyClass findByNameOrNull(List<MyClass> list, String name) {
  for(MyClass myClass: list)
    if(myClass.getName().equals(name))
      return myClass;
  return null
}
```

This is one of the problems that are easily solvable where lambdas are supported (here in Scala):

```
mylist.find(_.name == "xxx")
```

Comment: What does `find` return in `Scala` the object or the index? I assume it's the object, right?

Comment: Yes, it returns an object, or more precisely: an `Option` - a thin wrapper replacing `null`. Of course there is also `indexWhere()` that returns an index of the first element matching given predicate.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should override the equals method to use name to compare equality. You should also override `hashCode()` any time you override `equals()`, [read here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20).
2. You can use `indexOf()` to check if there are elements that match the given one. It uses `equals()`:

Here is how `yourlist.indexOf(o)` determines the match:

```
(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))
```

Then you can do `l.get(i)` on the index (i) that you found.